# Essential Business Server

Tags: windows-server-essentials

We are trying to run the Preparation Wizard for Essential Business Server 2008 and receive the following error.

"A list of servers could not be collected from Active Directory Domain Services (AD DS). Ensure that your network is functioning correctly and that this computer can access AD DS."

Our network is an Windows Server 2003 network with all of the services running fine.

I can't run this from either a machine or a server.

Any idea where we should start?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that this is kosher, but the [hyphen site has a good set of suggestions](http://74.125.153.132/search?q=cache:v-8LAxoGcN4J:www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft_Operating_Systems/Server/Essential_Business_Server/Q_23910090.html+http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft_Operating_Systems/Server/Essential_Business_Server/Q_23910090.html&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=au&client=firefox-a) for this problem.

To summarize, check the log at C:\Windows Essential Business Server\Wizards\Logs\WEBS.BPA.Console.log file - you may have a corrupt computer account in AD, or an account for a machine that doesn't exist any more.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Essential Business Server 2008 is the high-end equivilant to Small Business Server 2003 / 2008.

It can not be added to an existing domain.

Answer (score 0):

This product is now discontinued by Microsoft. The question is probably not valid anymore, as it was about the prep tool.

Source: http://www.microsoft.com/ebs/en/us/default.aspx